# Using PHP "prev" and "next" to Move Through an Array

Tags: php, arrays, cursor

I have two "buttons" to move the array cursor to the next record or to the prior record.  The function using "**next**" to move to the next (older) record works correctly.

However, the function to move to the prior ("**prev**") record (which is toward the top of the array) does not work correctly. I suspect that may be related to using "*mysqli_data_seek*". My belief was that it would set the cursor to the current location and then backtrack to the previous record. Instead the cursor continues to moves forward as if "**next**" was used instead of "**prev**". How can I backtrack to the prior record?

```
function return_next_issue()
    {
    // Newer Issue  - Moves up towards the top of the array.
    // mysqli_data_seek($_SESSION['result'], 0);
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($_SESSION['result'], MYSQL_NUM))
            {
                if($_SESSION['issuenum'] == $row[0]) 
                    {                                                       
                        break;
                    }   
            }   
    prev($_SESSION['result']);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_row($_SESSION['result']); 
    return $row[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the mysqli_result object is in the session and shared, you might want to initialize the internal pointer to 0 to make sure you know you are going to seek from the start. You can also create a variable that increments over the iteration to identify the index you need and seek for the previous one.

```
function return_next_issue()
{
   // Newer Issue  - Moves up towards the top of the array.
   $i = 0;
   mysqli_data_seek($_SESSION['result'], 0);
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($_SESSION['result'], MYSQL_NUM))
   {
      if($_SESSION['issuenum'] == $row[0]) 
      {                                                       
         break;
      }   
      $i++;

   }   
   mysqli_data_seek($_SESSION['result'], $i - 1);
   $row=mysqli_fetch_row($_SESSION['result']); 
   return $row[0];
}
```

Please note that your code won't work if $_SESSION['issuenum'] is 0 or if is greater than the number of rows available, and therefore so do the code I am providing.

Comment: Full Circle!!! That was my original version. I essentially outsmarted myself by trying to use PHP  features new to me.  Still have a lot to learn. The code has been restored to the original version as you identified. Thanks.